# How can I rotate a square to minimize the distance between each point and four arbitrary points?

Tags: javascript, geometry, p5.js, calculus, procedural-generation

I have been trying to follow this article:
https://andersource.dev/2020/11/06/organic-grid.html

Specifically, the appendix. But my understanding of calculus and its notation is limited.

So I tried also to understand and adapt/rewrite the source code:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andersource/andersource.github.io/master/assets/organic-grid/index.js

But it uses some libraries I'm unfamiliar with and I want to work from first principles.

Here is a simple example containing my code (all relevant code is in the `rotateSquareToFitQuad` function)

https://editor.p5js.org/marcusround/sketches/5jckZCCw-

[edit: this example has since been updated with the fix provided by andersource below] <s>But the resulting square seems to have an almost random rotation so I must have made some error in adapting the code.</s>

My goal is to minimise the total length of the four lines connecting each pair of vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of the math is correct. The culprit in this case is the notorious mismatch between the "up" direction of the y-axis between mathematics and many graphics utilities; this affects the "clockwise" assumption of the mathematical formulation in the article.

In your implementation you define the quadrants like this:

```
const quadrants = [
    [-1, -1], // TL
    [1, -1],  // TR
    [1, 1],   // BR
    [-1, 1],  // BL
  ]
```

This indeed renders the vertices in clockwise orientation, but results in counter-clockwise computation mathematically.

Replacing that with the following definition:

```
  const quadrants = [
    [-1, -1],
    [-1, 1],
    [1, 1],
    [1, -1],
  ]
```

Results in proper solutions (albeit counter-clockwise rendering of the vertices and shifted correspondences between the "fitted" square and the original vertices).

(An alternative solution is to re-derive the math in a "down is y-positive" system but that's probably an overkill.)

Comment: Ah, that old culprit! Thank you. By also adjusting the order of the `xyt` array, I was able to match up the vertices. Thanks again for a great article and for taking the time to debug.